USB wired mouse stops working after first clic on bootup
When I start my PC with Ubuntu 24.04, the first click of my mouse works and then it freezes. I have to disconnect and reconnect it for it to work again. This only happens when Ubuntu starts; it's not necessary to do it again. The mouse works fine on the same PC with Windows (I have dual boot). This has been happening since Ubuntu 20.04. I've updated to 22.04, 23.10, and 24.04, but none of these versions have solved my problem. The mouse is a HyperX Pulsefire Raid. Here are some logs, but doesn't seem to be useful. What you can see here is mouse startup and then my manual reconnection from usb port.
heisenberg@skyler:~$ sudo dmesg  | grep "usb 1-10"
[    2.130502] usb 1-10: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[    2.258883] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=16e4, bcdDevice=11.24
[    2.258895] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.258900] usb 1-10: Product: HyperX Pulsefire Raid
[    2.258904] usb 1-10: Manufacturer: Kingston
[ 3074.738021] usb 1-10: USB disconnect, device number 7
[ 3077.051363] usb 1-10: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 3077.179526] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=16e4, bcdDevice=11.24
[ 3077.179528] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 3077.179529] usb 1-10: Product: HyperX Pulsefire Raid
[ 3077.179530] usb 1-10: Manufacturer: Kingston

EDIT
I tried different usb ports, the problem persisted. I haven't tried a different mouse yet.

"I've updated to 22.04, 23.10, and 24.04, but none of these versions have solved my problem" by which you mean this problem has existed since the versions before 22.04? Have you tried using a different USB port on the PC and/or a different pointing device by way of trying to isolate any issue and what was the result? Add to your question by [edit].

I edited my original question to add the information you asked for.
